# RegEx to match 2-digit number in certain range

Tags: regex

I need to create a RegEx to verify the string input to a text box is exactly 2 digits long and is within the range 01-25 or 99.

I am new to creating my own RegEx and came up with:

```
[01-25,99]{2}
```

This verifies the number is 2 digits long, but it finds many matches outside of the indicated range.

Comment: what programming language you want this in?

Comment: It doesn't verify that the number is 2 digits long, it verifies that the character class matches twice, meaning it will happily match `,,`. That group is *a single character which is any of these: (a zero, a one-through-two, a five, a comma, a nine, a nine)*.

Comment: A regex shouldn't care about anything like this: its job is to care about matching syntax, i.e. digits, not semantics, i.e. their value. Just use `\d{2}`. The *next* bit of your code should determine whether the digits you matched are in the range you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character classes can contain *character* ranges, not *value* ranges.

Try this alternation:

```
0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-5]|99
```

If you want to limit the *entire* input to be such, wrap in `^` and `$`:

```
^0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-5]|99$
```

Comment: @sin ouch! Nice catch. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
 # ^(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-5]|99)$

 ^ 
 (?:
      0 [1-9] 
   |  1 \d 
   |  2 [0-5] 
   |  99
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something as dumb as (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5]|99)

Answer (score 1):

the way that regex works is as individual numbers, not as a range like you would assume. This means that your pattern :

```
[01-25,99]
```

would actually match anything that has a 0,1-2,5, a comma, or a 9 (saying it twice doesn't make a difference), and putting `{2} means that you are matching any string that has both of these in a row.

since it was answered while I was typing this, look at the pattern sln posted for one that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Also like this
[0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-5]|[99]